# getting "multiple definition" errors with simple device function in CUDA C

Tags: c, function, cuda, device

I have a simple script formed by 2 CUDA files: *main.cu* and *kernel.cu*. Their goal is to calculate the sum of 2 vectors.

```
// main.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda.h>

#include "kernel.cu"

int main(){
/* Error code to check return values for CUDA calls */
cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;   

srand(time(NULL));
int count = 100;
int A[count], B[count];
int *h_A, *h_B;
h_A = A; h_B = B;

int i;
for(i=0;i<count;i++){
    *(h_A+i) = rand() % count; /* Oppure: h_A[i] = rand() % count; */
    *(h_B+i) = rand() % count; /* Oppure: h_B[i] = rand() % count; */
}
/* Display dei vettori A e B. */
printf("\nPrimi cinque valori di A = ");
for(i=0;i<4;i++){printf("%d ", A[i]);}
printf("\nPrimi cinque valori di B = ");
for(i=0;i<4;i++){printf("%d ", B[i]);}


int *d_A, *d_B;

err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, count*sizeof(int));
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector A (error code %s)! \n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_B, count*sizeof(int));
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector A (error code %s)! \n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

err = cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, count*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector A from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
err = cudaMemcpy(d_B, B, count*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector A from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}


int numThreads = 256;
int numBlocks = count/numThreads + 1;
AddInts<<<numBlocks,numThreads>>>(d_A,d_B); err = cudaGetLastError(); 

err = cudaMemcpy(A, d_A, count*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector C from device to host (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

err = cudaFree(d_A); 
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector A (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
err = cudaFree(d_B); 
if (err != cudaSuccess){fprintf(stderr, "Failed to free device vector A (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

printf("\nPrimi cinque valori di A = ");
for(i=0;i<4;i++){printf("%d ", A[i]);}

printf("\n");
return 0;}
```

Here there's the *kernel.cu* file:

```
// kernel.cu
__device__ int get_global_index(){
return (blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
}

__global__ void AddInts(int *a, int *b){
           int ID = get_global_index();
           *(a+ID) += *(b+ID);

}
```

I am 100 % sure that the *main.cu* script is correct; I also know that i could just add the kernel directly in the the main script but that is not the intention of my test; I also know that I could just get rid of the `__device__` function and put it directly inside of the `__global__` but it's not my intention either.

When i compile the test by typing `nvcc main.cu kernel.cu` in the terminal I get however the following error message:

```
/tmp/tmpxft_0000248b_00000000-30_kernel.o: In function `get_global_index()':
tmpxft_0000248b_00000000-8_kernel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x15): multiple definition of `    get_global_index()'
/tmp/tmpxft_0000248b_00000000-21_main.o:tmpxft_0000248b_00000000-3_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x15): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_0000248b_00000000-30_kernel.o: In function `__device_stub__Z7AddIntsPiS_(int*, int*)':
tmpxft_0000248b_00000000-8_kernel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x7c): multiple definition of `__device_stub__Z7AddIntsPiS_(int*, int*)'
/tmp/tmpxft_0000248b_00000000-21_main.o:tmpxft_0000248b_00000000-3_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x68e): first defined here
/tmp/tmpxft_0000248b_00000000-30_kernel.o: In function `AddInts(int*, int*)':
tmpxft_0000248b_00000000-8_kernel.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xe5): multiple definition of `AddInts(int*, int*)'
/tmp/tmpxft_0000248b_00000000-21_main.o:tmpxft_0000248b_00000000-3_main.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x6f7): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I believe the error is caused by the definition of the the device function called *get_global_index()* but I don't understand what's wrong with it; does anyone have any idea of what it is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1. Just compile main.cu (`nvcc main.cu`)  It will already pick up `kernel.cu`, since you're including it.
2. Don't include `kernel.cu` in `main.cu`.

   When you include `kernel.cu` in `main.cu` (*and* pass both files to the compiler) it causes the compiler to compile that code (kernel.cu) *twice*, once when it is compiling `main.cu`, and once when it is compiling `kernel.cu`.   If you choose this option, you'll need to provide a prototype (forward reference) for  the `AddInts` kernel in `main.cu`, perhaps by inclusion of a header file with just that prototype.  And in the more general case, if you spread things out into more files, you may need to add `-rdc=true` to your compile command line, if you have files with `__global__` functions that are referencing `__device__` functions in other files, for example.